# Connection refused due to AJP failed to make connection to backend

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, jboss, ajp

While running application in my local, It starts properly first time. But when I restart again, It shows :

> (111)Connection refused: proxy: AJP: attempt to connect to 192.168.1.182:8009 (docker.reverse.host) failed
>   [Thu Feb 14 06:41:51 2019] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (docker.reverse.host)
>   [Thu Feb 14 06:41:51 2019] [error] proxy: AJP: failed to make connection to backend: docker.reverse.host

I am using :

1. Jboss as App server.
2. Tomcat as Web server.
3. Containerized application in docker.

Detailed log is :

> Thu Feb 14 04:21:41 2019] [error] ajp_read_header: ajp_ilink_receive failed
>   [Thu Feb 14 04:21:41 2019] [error] (120006)APR does not understand this error code: proxy: read response failed from (null) (localhost)
>   [Thu Feb 14 04:21:41 2019] [error] ajp_read_header: ajp_ilink_receive failed
>   [Thu Feb 14 04:21:41 2019] [error] (120006)APR does not understand this error code: proxy: read response failed from (null) (localhost)
>   [Thu Feb 14 04:21:42 2019] [error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: AJP: attempt to connect to 192.168.1.182:8009 (docker.reverse.host) failed
>   [Thu Feb 14 04:21:42 2019] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (docker.reverse.host)
>   [Thu Feb 14 04:21:42 2019] [error] proxy: AJP: failed to make connection to backend: docker.reverse.host
>   [Thu Feb 14 04:21:42 2019] [error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: AJP: attempt to connect to 192.168.1.182:8009 (docker.reverse.host) failed
>   [Thu Feb 14 04:21:42 2019] [error] proxy: AJP: failed to make connection to backend: docker.reverse.host
>   [Thu Feb 14 04:22:10 2019] [error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: AJP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8009 (localhost) failed
>   [Thu Feb 14 04:22:10 2019] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
>   [Thu Feb 14 04:22:10 2019] [error] proxy: AJP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost
>   [Thu Feb 14 04:22:11 2019] [error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: AJP: attempt to connect to 192.168.1.182:8009 (docker.reverse.host) failed
>   [Thu Feb 14 04:22:11 2019] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (docker.reverse.host)
>   [Thu Feb 14 04:22:11 2019] [error] proxy: AJP: failed to make connection to backend: docker.reverse.host
>   [Thu Feb 14 06:25:43 2019] [error] ajp_read_header: ajp_ilink_receive failed
>   [Thu Feb 14 06:25:43 2019] [error] (120006)APR does not understand this error code: proxy: read response failed from (null) (localhost)
>   [Thu Feb 14 06:25:43 2019] [error] ajp_read_header: ajp_ilink_receive failed
>   [Thu Feb 14 06:25:43 2019] [error] (120006)APR does not understand this error code: proxy: read response failed from (null) (localhost)
>   [Thu Feb 14 06:25:44 2019] [error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: AJP: attempt to connect to 192.168.1.182:8009 (docker.reverse.host) failed
>   [Thu Feb 14 06:25:44 2019] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (docker.reverse.host)
>   [Thu Feb 14 06:25:44 2019] [error] proxy: AJP: failed to make connection to backend: docker.reverse.host
>   [Thu Feb 14 06:25:44 2019] [error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: AJP: attempt to connect to 192.168.1.182:8009 (docker.reverse.host) failed
>   [Thu Feb 14 06:25:44 2019] [error] proxy: AJP: failed to make connection to backend: docker.reverse.host
>   [Thu Feb 14 06:41:50 2019] [error] ajp_read_header: ajp_ilink_receive failed
>   [Thu Feb 14 06:41:50 2019] [error] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: proxy: read response failed from (null) (localhost)
>   [Thu Feb 14 06:41:51 2019] [error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: AJP: attempt to connect to 192.168.1.182:8009 (docker.reverse.host) failed
>   [Thu Feb 14 06:41:51 2019] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (docker.reverse.host)
>   [Thu Feb 14 06:41:51 2019] [error] proxy: AJP: failed to make connection to backend: docker.reverse.host